# Button text set to TextView

Tags: android

I have three buttons like Button1, Button2, and Button3. All these buttons have different text, and I want to display the text of these buttons in one TextView.

When I click on button1 then display the text of button1 and when click on button2 then display the Text of button2 in same TextView, but the first one is removed like same applicable on button3. Only one button text shows at one time in TextView.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve]

Comment: Unclear what you want, but simply calling setText with a new value will never append any text into the TextView

Comment: I have two activities in first activity i have three button on first button i wrote ABC on second button i wrote DEF and on third button i wrote GHI. In second Activity i have only one TextView, Now i want when i click on first button then display ABC in TextView and when i click on second button then display DEF and when click on third button then display GHI.

Comment: Check my answer, I think it will help you

Answer (score 1):

`textView.setText()` will replace the existing text in your `TextView`. If you want to keep previous text as it is in the `TextView` then you need to use `textView.append("<your text>");`

Comment: * **textView.setText()**

Answer (score 0):

For your first button text you should do like textView.setText(button1text) and to concatenate the rest of the buttons text you should do like textView.append(button2textorbutton3text).